# Re-size one axis of a plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

This a quite easy questions I didn't manage to find some old topic about it.

I'm doing plots and I change the data lim, especifically the xlim, (I take out like 60-70% of the graph away with that). 
But when I do this, it makes my graph look really small, and than I can't extract anything from it. How can I resize the x-axis so I can see it more clearly.

Comment: It sounds like you're doing the right thing -- calling `xlim` is the right way to resize one axis. Are you sure you're giving it the right numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, matplotlib does what you want for line plots, etc.

Somewhere in your code, you're probably setting a fixed aspect ratio and setting the adjustable part of the axis boundary to `"box"` rather than `"datalim"`.

More likely, something you're calling is doing this without you being aware of it. For example, if you call `plt.imshow` it does this by default (It essentially calls `plt.axis('image')` which sets the aspect to 1.0 and adjustable to "box") so that images aren't stretched to odd ratios.

There are several ways to fix it. The easiest is to just call `plt.axis('tight')` before resizing the x-axis with `plt.xlim`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.random.random((10,10))

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(data, interpolation='nearest')
plt.title('Original Plot')

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(data, interpolation='nearest')
plt.xlim([2, 4])
plt.title('Resized Plot')

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(data, interpolation='nearest')
plt.axis('tight')
plt.xlim([2, 4])
plt.title('Resized Plot with Tight Axis')

plt.show()
```

[image]
[image]
[image]